# Leaflet.draw prevent events

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have added the draw control to my Mapbox map and only have polygon enabled.  I'm attempting to prevent the draw tool from going into draw mode if the user has not zoomed into a certain level.  I have added a click event to the polygon button using it's class, but I cannot figure out what call I need to make to cancel the draw.

```
$('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').on('click', function (e) {
        if (map.getZoom() < 13)
            //Cancel draw
        else
            drawingPolygon = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the zoom level whenever the zoom is changed? From the [leaflet reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomlevelschange), there's a `zoomlevelchange` event, so you could something like:

```
map.on('zoomlevelchange' function() {
    if (map.getZoom() < 13)
        //Remove and disable the drawing control
    else
        //Enable drawing
});
```